# How can I stop NTP from updating my system clock?

Tags: ntp

Please bear with me on this slightly odd request!

I have a [debian linux] system with an internal [RTC] clock which the user can adjust or change. It may or may not be connected to external IP and therefore may or may not have access to NTP. I would like to provide an option in the clock setting UI to "set from NTP" if it is available, but I don't want the system clock to be constantly updated from NTP.

- How can I configure ntpd to be active, but not update the system
  clock?
- How can I read and display the 'ntp time' (which will be shown
  along with the system clock)?

system is debian jessie.
reading and displaying the time in C or python.

Comment: You probably would get a better answer on this question on either unix.stackexchange.com or superuser.stackexchange.com.  The question as it stands is too vague to be answered since you've not bothered to specify which language (C, Python) or which version of Debian Linux or most of the details which are necessary to provide you with a useful answer to this.  Vote to close.

Answer (score 0):

will disable ntpd and use occasional NTP requests to update a local "network time offset" from system time.